# Want Program logic in PHP To display string

Tags: php, logic

I am having input as Word "CODE"

and I want to get output as "CCOCODCODE"

Please help me with the logic to print this output.

Thanks.

Comment: What logic ? What have you tried ?

Comment: can you be more specific as to what this logic is?

Comment: I think I get his 'logic'. He take the first letter of CODE (so C) then 2 letters (CCO) then 3 (CCOCOD) and finnaly the entire word (CCOCODCODE)

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple. Looking at your pattern, you need to concatenate all possible prefixes of `CODE` one after the other. So, maintain a `result` variable and keep concatenating substrings with `0` as the start point and end point being each index in the string.

```
<?php

$str = 'CODE';
$result = '';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);++$i){
    $result .= substr($str,0,$i+1);
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid loops whenever you can.
Short and simple does the trick :-)

```
<?PHP
$Text = 'CODE';
echo implode(array_map(function($Position) use ($Text) { return substr($Text,0,$Position+1); },array_keys(str_split($Text))));
```